# Tag score calculation wrong in Android App

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, android-app, tag-score

I checked yesterday and today the new homepage in the Android app. Very surprised I saw that I would almost reach a silver tag badge, that confused be because I always take a look on possible badges I can get. However I compared the score with the website and I got a total different results. See this two screenshots:

[image: app]
[image: web]

Comment: At 72 DPI your phone is 8"x14.2". Tell us the truth, are you Bigfoot's long lost brother Bighand?

Comment: No I use a HTC One with a 4.7 inch, Full HD 1080p, 468 PPI screen.

Comment: That makes more sense (but is less fun to imagine).

Comment: Yeah that is true :D

Answer (score 18):

The calculation is correct, we're just displaying a different number in the app. On the website, the displayed tag score is your *answer* score in that tag, and you can get the value for questions by hovering your mouse over the score value. In the app, we show the combined *question-and-answer* score. The tooltip of the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag on your profile reads

> Asked 37 non-wiki questions with a total score of 149. Gave 187 non-wiki answers with a total score of 219.

and 149+219=368. The count in both cases contains questions and answers.

Honestly, we weren't sure how to handle this in the app were there's no such thing as a tooltip. We discussed it but couldn't come to a real conclusion, so we just picked one solution for now; we're open to changing how it's displayed if a good case can be made for any version.

Comment: I would say use the same value like in the web . I didn't note that I could display that combined value on the website. For the badge only the answers count right so display only that *relevant* value.

Comment: It could be renamed to something like Tag Participation to at least signal to a user that this is not the same field shown on the web profile. I was really confused when I saw a  30+ score on the app in a tag and just 3 on the web profile.

Comment: There's no such thing as a tooltip on mobile, correct, but why change it in the app, but not on the mobile site?

Comment: I just got confused about it today as well. I even posted another question about it here on meta. I would make it the same as on web for 2 reasons: the discrepancy makes it confusing and the score in answers is more important than the score in questions.

Comment: I guess the calculation is the same for the iOS app too then, huh? Because I've noticed that my tag scores are higher in the app.

Comment: Definitely a bad idea to show different values depending on where the user accesses their profile. It creates confusion. If you absolutely need to show the totals, add a long-press to the tags with a Toast message (or something similar).

Comment: I have just had to look this up because my 'score' is showing 1000 in a tag... but I'm still a way short on the real total. Q/A totals e.g. `19:981` might be less confusing.

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293404/tag-score-in-app-should-be-for-answers-only)

Comment: It's _status-by-poor-design_.