# Stack Exchange app and web version - tag score discrepancy

Tags: bug, android-app, tag-score

While checking out the Stack Exchange app on Android, I noticed a discrepancy in the score in one of my tags ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)) on Stack Overflow.

On the web, my score is 322:

[image]

In the app, my score is 336:

[image]

I don't know which one is correct though.

App version is 1.0.3

Comment: it's an dup but don't have time to find it at this exact moment.... the tag score in the app is question+answwer, whereas the web sit4e is answer only

Comment: Thanks guys, that's the exact case. I'm voting to close it as duplicate. I would say it is very confusing though.

Comment: it is and if you notice [balpha's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/182513) last paragraph, they are open to change it.  If you can come up with a good way to resolve the discrepancy, make a feature request.