# Question Score not included in Tag Badges

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges

I first realised that [the tag count on android is different than on the website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app). This is due to the fact that the app shows *both* the answer & question score of a badge.

Then I checked [the badge help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to find out that *only* answers count towards the `Tag Badges`.

I wanted to know why the question score does not play a role regarding these badges. Are questions considered less valuable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions aren't less valuable, no. Eventually, if there were no questions, there would be no answers.

But tag score intended to show how  *knowledgable* you are  in this tag. 
For example, if you have close / reopen priveleges and a [gold tag badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold), you can close / reopen a question initially having this tag with one vote.

So I think you agree that answers show your knowledge more than questions :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm unsure if answers show more knowledge than questions.   How would you argue that this is the case?

Comment: @TheChamp But you can ask a quetstions almost without knowing anything. But answering certainly requires some knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

Questions are not included in the tag score because it indicates a user's expertise in that field, which is measured by the quality of the answers they provide.
When a asker posts a question, they gain the knowledge from the answerer, so the user who contributes the answer has more of knowledge among the two in the field.

However, questions have a lot of value, and the number of questions a user posts do play a role in the total number of posts that are displayed on the right side of every tag on a user's profile. They are a good indicator for knowing a user's *field of interest.*

The primary differentiation is between interest and expertise of a user. Tag badges are for experts.