# Tag score in app should be for answers only

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, ios-app

When viewing tag counts in my profile, I get different numbers in the app than I do on the website. I gather that [this behaviour is intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app) and not a bug.

Given that answer score is the measure by which badges are awarded, and is the number shown in profiles on the site, I feel the apps should use the answer score and not the combined question and answer score.

Web site:
[image: Screenshot]

App:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag score calculation wrong in Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app)

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't aware this was the behaviour. Will adjust my bug report to a feature request!

Answer (score 2):

From [balpha♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/312043)

> Honestly, we weren't sure how to handle this in the app were there's no such thing as a tooltip. We discussed it but couldn't come to a real conclusion, so we just picked one solution for now; we're open to changing how it's displayed if a good case can be made for any version.

Since app doesn't have the tooltip, they already discussed about this case, and didn't find the solution for this.