# Tag Tally Discrepancy between Web and Mobile Client

Tags: bug

**Mobile App: Stack Exchange iOS App version 1.6.6.2**

Does anyone else have a discrepancy between their Tag Tallies when looking in the web (my [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) profile):

[image]

as compared to my dba.se profile in the mobile app:

[image]

In particular, I'm looking at the `389` vs `486` for the `sql-server` tag (as well as the other `sql-server-20XX` tags) and also the total count being reflected of `186` vs `166`.  I'm not worried about the numbers so much as the fact that they just don't match.

Upon further digging this looks like this is site agnostic as my Stack Overflow profile shows similar discrepancies matching the calculation breakdowns as identified by [Peter Vandivier](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68127/peter-vandivier) in the answers below.

Stack Overflow Web site:

[image]

Stack Overflow Profile in Mobile Client:

[image]

Comment: My screen is slightly different from yours, are you running the latest version? Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.95

Comment: @McNets Yes, it's up-to-date.  I'm running Version 1.6.6.2 on iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app/212315#212315), this looks to be intentional.

The desktop site aggregation sums only answers while mobile sums both questions and answers (display format being `sum-tag-count`). Curiously - drill down on both sites reveals all posts regardless of type. Count appears to be consistent between the two.

Anecdotally from [my top tags](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68127/peter-vandivier?tab=tags&sort=votes) (as of right now, see screencaps below) I'll select a few that are easy to compare

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|                 | mobile      | desktop     |
+-----------------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| tag             | sum | count | sum | count |
+-----------------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| restore         | 13  | 3     | 8   | 3     |
+-----------------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| powershell      | 11  | 5     | 7   | 5     |
+-----------------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| sql-server-2012 | 11  | 4     | 7   | 4     |
+-----------------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
```

[restore drill-down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:68127+[restore]) ([screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LelhR.png)) shows...

- +1 (answer)
- +7 (answer)
- +5 (question)

..which should be `13/3 mobile | 8/3 desktop`

[powershell drill-down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:68127+[powershell]) ([screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goift.png)) shows...

- +2 (question)
- +2 (answer)
- +2 (question)
- +1 (answer)
- +4 (answer)

...which should be `11/5 mobile | 7/5 desktop`

[sql-server-2012 drill-down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:68127+[sql-server-2012]) ([screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv5z8.png)) shows...

- +1 (answer)
- +2 (answer)
- +2 (answer) (community wiki - but this isn't displayed in the summary page)
- +4 (answer)
- +4 (question)

...which should be `13/5 mobile | 9/5 desktop` until you exclude the community wiki answer which brings it to the displayed tallies of `11/4 mobile | 7/4 desktop`

[image: mobile-site-petervandivier-top-tags]

[image: desktop-site-petervandivier-top-tags]

Comment: That does look to be what’s going on.  Nice digging!  Now I wonder, is it intended to be different between the two on purpose?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener apparently yes. [It is intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/299676) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯